# Insert dates in cell from a combobox

Tags: excel, vba, date, combobox

I want to insert date in cell from my form with Combobox. I made my button look the way I want, but when I insert the date in the cell there is in text format. How to set the value in the cell in date format?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Integer

Combobox1.List = Worksheets(3).Range("AM3:AM13").Value

For i = 0 To Combobox1.ListCount - 1
    Combobox1.List(i) = Format(DateValue(Combobox1.List(i)), "dd mmm")
Next i

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
 'Nothing here
End Sub

Private Sub InsertButton_Click()
    ActiveCell.Value = Combobox1.Value
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: `ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "{pick your format}"` before you add the date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. This change the format of the cell, but after that date in the cell is in text format. I think is necessary to change something here:   

`Combobox1.List(i) = Format(DateValue(Combobox1.List(i)), "dd mmm")`

Comment: What format did you use? "dd mmm" worked fine for me (but since there's no year in your combobox it will default to the current year on the worksheet).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. See what's the difference between the two dates. Some functions have a problem with a different format and not working correct.

[When I insert a date with a Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGzLX.png)

[When I insert a date without a combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQWXD.png)